# Python Pandas Create Cooccurence Matrix from two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which looks like this (The columns are filled with ids for a movie and ids for an actor:

```
    movie  actor  clusterid
0    0      1     2
1    0      2     2
2    1      1     2
3    1      3     2
4    2      2     1
```

and i want to create a binary co-occurence matrix from this dataframe which looks like this

```
                  actor1  actor2  actor3
clusterid 2 movie0    1      1     0
            movie1    1      0     1
clusterid 1 movie2    0      1     0
```

where my dataframe has (i) a multiindex (clusterid, movieid) and a binary count for actors which acted in the movie according to my inital dataframe.

I tried:

```
df.groupby("movie").agg('count').unstack(fill_value=0)
```

but unfortunately this doesn't expand the dataframe and counts the totals. Can something like this be done using the internal pandas functions easily?

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extra auxiliary column to indicate if the value exists and then do `pivot_table`:

```
(df.assign(actor = "actor" + df.actor.astype(str), indicator = 1)
 .pivot_table('indicator', ['clusterid', 'movie'], 'actor', fill_value = 0))
```

[image]

Or use `set_index.unstack()` pattern:

```
(df.assign(actor = "actor" + df.actor.astype(str), indicator = 1)
 .set_index(['clusterid', 'movie', 'actor']).indicator.unstack('actor', fill_value=0))
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it the same if i use the aggfunc=len parameter for a pivot table? like for example: pivot_table(index='movie', columns='actor', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

Comment: In that case, you lose the `clusterid`, if you are ok with it, i think it's an option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your explanation